# Javascript snipet error in render function in a react application - '}' expected

Tags: javascript, syntax, curly-braces

I am writing a simple react code that has a certain portion of javascript which is throwing me an error

```
var React = require('react');
var Link = require('react-router').Link;

var openColumnAnalysis = React.createClass({

  render: function(){
        return(
            <body>
                <div>
                    <Link to={"/"}>Reports Home</Link>
                    <input type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="myFunction()" placeholder="Search for Reports.."></input>
                    <ul id="myUL">
                          <li>
                                <a href="myLink" target="_blank">Map Report</a>
                          </li>
                          <li>
                                <a href="myLink" target="_blank">Customer Report</a>
                          </li>
                    </ul>

                </div>
                <script>
                    function myFunction()
                    {
                        // document.write("Hi")
                        filter = document.getElementById('myInput').value
                        li_tag = document.getElementById('myUL').getElementsByTagName('li')

                        for (i = 0; i < li_tag.length; i++)
                        {
                            a_tag = li_tag[i].getElementsByTagName('a')[0];
                            if (a_tag.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1)
                            {
                                li_tag[i].style.display = "";
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                li_tag[i].style.display = "none";
                            }
                        }
                    }

                </script>
            </body>
        );
  }
  });
module.exports = openColumnAnalysis;
```

the 'document.write("Hi")' statement works perfectly. But even if I just write 'var inp;' and nothing else.. I start getting an error like '} expected'!

I don't understand where this is going wrong... I am following this link : https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_filter_lists.asp for this learning.

Edit: Pasting my code as ref as asked.. :) If I remove the script tag, then the code runs fine... but I am trying to filter the li tags here based on search input..
Thanking you in advance!

Comment: Remember to be disciplined when indenting your code!

Comment: Could you post the code for the whole file? It seems to me that the error is not in this snippet.

Comment: Can you add the code which gives the error?

Comment: @Grandas please not the whole file... we need a [mcve]

Comment: There is not a single error in this snippet, please complete your question by adding the exact code snippet.

Comment: Hi @shubham I have added the code

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your help, but I got an answer here. For some reason I am not sure script tags are not working when defined inside the return statement of any react function. So I created another function to perform the filtering and called the same in the render function as below:

```
filterRepo: function(){
    return(
        function myFunction() {
            var filter = document.getElementById('myInput').value.toUpperCase();
            var li = document.getElementById("myUL").getElementsByTagName('li');

            // Loop through all list items, and hide those who don't match the search query
            for (i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
                a = li[i].getElementsByTagName("a")[0];
                if (a.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
                    li[i].style.display = "";
                } else {
                    li[i].style.display = "none";
                }
            }
        }
    );

},
render: function(){
    var repoLink = this.state.repoLinks;
    repoLink = repoLink.map(function(item, index){
        return(
            <OpenReport key={index} desc={item.description} ); 
    }.bind(this));

    return(
        <div id="inside_repoInfo">
            <br></br>
            <input type="text" id="myInput" onKeyUp={this.filterRepo()} placeholder="Search for Report.."></input>
            <ul id="myUL" >{repoLink}</ul>
        </div>
    );
}
```

The rest of the code if only to display the list tag which I have defined in OpenReport component.

Hope this helps others!